# Protecting my PHP page from unauthorized queries

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, encryption

I have a simple PHP script that takes a query, and enters it into a database. The server is set up on a virtual machine at Amazon. The queries are made as follows:

```
http://website.se/file.php?unit1&This+is+a+text
```

I'd like to stop just anyone from entering things into the database, and I'd like to do it not only by keeping the URL secret.

Any suggestions on what I should do? Encryption? The security is not of greatest importance in this case, I prefer a somewhat simple solution.

Comment: A login system with sessions?

Comment: htaccess? I would never allow a query to be executed from the query string though personally.

Comment: Then define what the permissible access rules are first and foremost.

Answer (score 0):

Not trusting the secrecy of your url is the right way to go.
If you want it simple, use .htaccess. If you want it right, use a login system.
Or just consider installing phpMyAdmin, it might serve your needs.

Remember: Unless you use ssl, consider the script vulnerable.

Comment: Can I use SSL in Linux without having an "officially generated" SSL certificate? Would that be an idea?

Comment: You can create your own ssl certificate. That will generate a warning on first visit scaring any visitors, but I guess that´s not an issue here, and the connection is encrypted.

Comment: Scary messages are indeed not an issue, as the site isn't for the public. Is htaccess without a secure SSL connection a really bad idea?

Comment: Depends on your demands. If you are keeping track of books you lent someone, it´s ok. If you are keeping track of limousines you rented, you might want to invest the additional dollars for ssl.